# How can I get my code to output the nonzero elements from a matrix?

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector, adjacency-matrix

I have an adjacency matrix I am trying to work with (not in graph theory but in Computational Physics), and I have spliced together some stuff I've scavenged throughout the internet in C++, which is what the rest of the project is written in. I have defined an arbitrary adjacency matrix (9x9), and am trying to get the non zero elements of each row into a vector. I get the following result, 1 1 1 1 1 1 6 1 6 1 6, when I run this code:

```
  int x[9][9] = 
{{0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},{1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0}, 
{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};

{
 vector<int> col;
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)

    {
        if (x[0][j] == 1)
        {
            col.push_back(j);
        }
        else{}
        std::copy(col.begin(), col.end(), 
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

I expect to get 1 6, and even though these are the only two integers in the resulting output, I am confused why it isn't just "1 6". Is there any error I am missing here, or any other way to get my desired result of the non zero elements from the constituent arrays?

Comment: `I get the following result, 1 1 1 1 1 1 6 1 6 1 6` you should put `std::copy` line out of the loop. Because you are looping the `elements of array` not the arrays - the `x[0]`, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should loop over a matrix's arrays and over their values, so take a look:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

  int x[9][9] = 
    {{0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},{1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0}, 
    {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0}, 
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},{0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};

int main() {
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++){ // loop over matrix's arrays
        std::vector<int> col;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) { // loop over array
            if (x[j][i] == 1) {
                col.push_back(i);
            }
            //else{}
        }
        std::cout << "Array index: " << j << std::endl;
        std::copy(col.begin(), col.end(), 
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
Array index: 0
1 6
Array index: 1
0 3 8
Array index: 2
4 5
Array index: 3
1
Array index: 4
2
Array index: 5
2
Array index: 6
0 7
Array index: 7
6
Array index: 8
1
```